# Running Tomcat in eclipse Luna "Exception loading sessions from persistent storage "

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, primefaces

```
Ara 17, 2014 10:00:05 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager startInternal
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: gov.tbb.eys.service.impl.MenuServiceImpl
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:500)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.readObject(AdvisedSupport.java:557)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObject(StandardSession.java:1619)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1084)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: gov.tbb.eys.service.impl.MenuServiceImpl
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObject(StandardSession.java:1695)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1101)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:430)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5683)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1580)
    ... 4 more

Ara 17, 2014 10:00:05 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Ara 17, 2014 10:00:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Ara 17, 2014 10:00:05 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Ara 17, 2014 10:00:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10112 ms
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee &lt;a href=" http:="" java.sun.com="" xml="" ns="" javaee="" web-app_3_0.xsd"="">">http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

------------------------------------web.xml-----------------------------

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>#{themeBean.theme}</param-value>  
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>anasayfa.jsf</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/anasayfa.jsf</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

-------------------------------------applicationContext.xml---------------------------------

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans &lt;a href=" http:="" www.springframework.org="" schema="" beans="" spring-beans-4.0.xsd"="">http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx ">http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="gov.tbb.eys" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sybase:Tds:localhost:2638/db" />
    <property name="username" value="eysAdmin" />
    <property name="password" value="eys2014" />
</bean> 
<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <!-- <property name="showSql" value="true"/> -->
    <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/> -->
    <property name="database" value="SYBASE" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="gov.tbb_eys_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<context:annotation-config />
</beans>
```

---------------------MenuBean.java--------------------------------

```
@ManagedBean(name = "menuBean") 
@SessionScoped public class MenuBean implements Serializable { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{menuService}")
private IMenuService menuService;
```

----------------------IMenuService.java-----------------------------------------

```
public interface IMenuService {

List<Menu> findAllMenu();

List<MenuItem> findAllMenuItem();

List<MenuItem> findMenuItemByMenu(Menu menu);

Tema findTema();

void saveTema(Tema tema);
}
```

-----------------------MenuServiceImpl.java--------------------------------------------

```
@Transactional 
@Service(value="menuService") 
public class MenuServiceImpl implements IMenuService {

@Autowired 
private IMenuDao menuDao;

@Autowired
private IMenuItemDao menuItemDao;

@Override
public List<MenuItem> findAllMenuItem() {
    return menuItemDao.findAllMenuItem();
}
.......
```

-----------------------IMenuDao.java--------------------------------------------------

```
public interface IMenuDao {

List<Menu> findAllMenu();

Tema findTema();

void saveTema(Tema tema);
}
```

--------------------MenuDaoImpl.java---------------------------------

```
@Repository 
public class MenuDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<integer, menu=""> implements IMenuDao{

@Override
public List<Menu> findAllMenu() {

    TypedQuery<Menu> query =  getEm().createNamedQuery("Menu.findAll", Menu.class);
    List<Menu> results = query.getResultList();

    return results;
}
..............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem is that your `MenuBean`'s property `IMenuService menuService` is not serializable. Each Serialized Managed Bean should have Serializable Managed Properties.